# How do I use window load spinner style percentage? The percentage starts from 1 and when 100 is the load will end and my page will show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I made it ... but it has nothing to do with Pageload**

[image]

How do I setup a pageload relationship with it?

**my js code**

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
    }, 4000);


var $circ = $('.animated-circle');
var $progCount = $('.progress-count');
var percentage=parseInt($('.progress-count').html());



function stopProgress(){
  clearInterval(progress);
}

var progress= setInterval(function(){

  percentage++;
  if (percentage<=100){

    if (percentage>10) {
      var circle_offset = 1.26 * percentage;
        $circ.css({
            "stroke-dashoffset" : 126 - circle_offset
        });
      $('.progress-count').html(percentage+'%');
      console.log(percentage);
    }
  }
  else {
    stopProgress()
  }
},40);
```

***I set the load time constants in callback. But How Will set  This load time in  Data Load Time?***

Comment: How are you expecting to calculate how much data has been loaded of the total page size?

Comment: Is it in any way
Not possible

Comment: Not really. The only way Javascript can determine the size of images or linked files is to request them and load their data, but then the point of the loader is moot as you've already loaded the files to calculate the loading time to load the files :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the snippet below if it helps.

```js
var height = 100,
    perfData = window.performance.timing, // The PerformanceTiming interface represents timing-related performance information for the given page.
    EstimatedTime = -(perfData.loadEventEnd - perfData.navigationStart),
    time = parseInt((EstimatedTime/1000)%60)*100;

// Loadbar Animation
$(".loadbar").animate({
  height: height + "%"
}, time);

// Fading Out Loadbar on Finised
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.preloader-wrap').fadeOut(300);
}, time);
```

```css
.preloader-wrap{position: fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)}
.loader{ width: 110px; height: 110px; border-radius:50%; background-color: black; position:relative; overflow:hidden; left:0; right:0; top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%); margin:0 auto;}
.trackbar { width: 110px;; height: 110px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: white; padding: 0; position: absolute; border-radius: 50%; left: 0; right: 0; top: 50%; transform:translateY(-50%)}
.loadbar{ position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background-color: skyblue; }
.trackbar:after{content:''; position:absolute; top:50%; left:0; right:0; margin:0 auto; width:90px; height:90px; background-color: black; border-radius: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader-wrap">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="trackbar">
      <div class="loadbar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But isn't this based on an estimate - where the OP is asking specifically how to calculate the actual load time to make the load percentage meaningful? Its a decent demo of a progress indicator but not on subject, so I will be downvoting.

Comment: you are use callback time .how to use callback dataload time ?

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery widow.load(), something like this

```
<script>
////start your loader here outside every other method, in the start of your script
</script>
```

at last do the following

```
$(window).load(function() {
    stopProgress();
});
```

The window.load will execute once everything else on page executed